# Android imageview not displaying in TableRow

Tags: android, imageview, tablerow

I am trying to display a simple ImageView in a TableRow but for some reason it won't display. If I add another control to another row the imageView does display, so it seems like it is just not forcing the size correctly. My xml is as follows:

```
<TableLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:background="#4B088A"
  android:id="@+id/ImageTable">

 <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:padding="5dp"
 android:id="@+id/ImageTableRow"/> 

  </TableLayout>
```

The code that I am using to add the ImageView is:

```
TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.ImageTable);  

TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);

TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new 
        TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT ,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

tr.setLayoutParams(lp);

 m_imageView = new MyImageView(getApplicationContext());

 m_imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

 m_imageView.setImageBitmap(charty);

 tr.addView(m_imageView);

 tableLayout.addView(tr);
```

Comment: is you require to add image using java code or using xml is also ok?and is you declare your m_imageView

Comment: @Sumedh Tambat I have also tried to add the ImageView using XML but unless there is another control in the Table the ImageView doesn't display. I am new to Android so it is probably my understanding of how TableLayout works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code:

Write your `activity_main.xml` as

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_search" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

`ic_action_search` is your image in the "Drawable" folder, and write `MainActivity.java` as

```java
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    
    ImageView image;
    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```